# How does a DCP USB Type-C port work when connectors don't have D+/- pins

Tags: usb-c, usb-pd

I'm interested in building a circuit that implements charging via a USB type-c receptacle as a "direct charging port".

I've found some Type-C connectors that are advertised as "charge only" but they don't seem to include D-/+ pins. My understanding is that a DCP needs to expose the D-/+ pins to at least allow shorting them for the minimum spec, or setting specific voltages for more complex setups.

An example of a connector with no D-/+ pins: https://gct.co/files/drawings/usb4130.pdf

How you would use one of these connectors in a DCP scenario?

Answer (score 1):

USB-C uses USB PD communication on the CC pins. It does not need or use D-/D+ pins for communication.

Comment: I understand that this is the case for PD negotiation of exotic voltages but as I understand a type-C cable can emulate a "USB Battery Charging" for backwards compatibility using the D-/+ method. I guess this just mean that this plug simply doesn't support that mode